# JSON to XML Conversion for String

Tags: json, node.js, xslt

I need to convert the following JSON between the String tags into XML format

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"> 
{"IResp":0,"SDescripcion":"OC: 2000041574. Proceso exitoso."}</string>
```

the above should be converted as

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
       <IResp>0</IResp>
       <SDescription>"OC: 2000041574. Proceso exitoso"</SDescription>
</String>
```

Comment: why don't you convert that JSON to xml while creating the xml document?

Comment: in addition to what @divine said, try using [jstoxml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstoxml) for conversion

Comment: i am trying to do like that but i am getting many errors. I am very new to this XSLT

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
<xsl:template match="xx:string">
  <xsl:variable name="content" select="parse-json(.)" as="map(*)"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <IResp>{content?IResp}</IResp>
    <SDescription>{content?SDescription}</SDescription>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```